# Throw error in case_clause when returning handle_call value

Tags: erlang

I want the handle_call \ 3 to return me a tuple of the following form {message, timestamp, integer} and then in the case clause, it gives me an error when I should enter through the branch corresponding to that response.

Attach an example

```
execute(Method, Url, Headers, Body, PoolId) ->
    BeforeGetConn = erlang:now(),
    TimeStartBusy = undefined,
    PosBusy = undefined,
    TimeStartBusyAfterWait = undefined,
    PosBusyAfterWait = undefined,
    TimeInWaiting = undefined,
    PosWaiting = undefined,
    ShouldContinue =
    case gen_server:call(?MODULE, {get_conn, PoolId, self(), BeforeGetConn}) of
        proceed -> ok;
        {wait, Ref, PosWaiting} ->
            ...
        %Throw error in the following line
        {proceed, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy} -> {ok, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy};
        unknown_pool -> ...
    end,
    case ShouldContinue of
        {ok, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy}  ->
           execute_process(...);
        ...
    end.

handle_call({get_conn, PoolId, Caller, Time}, _From, #state{pools = Pools} = State) ->
  case proplists:get_value(PoolId, Pools) of
    undefined ->
      ...
    Pool ->
      case is_busy_full(Pool) of
        false ->
          Pool2 = add_to_busy({Caller}, Pool),
          TimeStartBusy = os:timestamp(),
          PosBusy = queue:len(Pool2#pool.busy),
          {reply,
          {proceed, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy},
          State#state{pools = [{PoolId, Pool2} |
                                proplists:delete(PoolId, Pools)]}};
        true ->
          ...
      end
  end;
```

The error I see on the console is the following:

> exit with reason:
> {[{reason,{case_clause,{proceed,{1614,588434,663546},1}}}

Thank you

Code edited:

```
ShouldContinue =
    case gen_server:call(?MODULE, {get_conn, PoolId, self(), BeforeGetConn}) of
        proceed -> ok;
        {wait, Ref, PosWaiting} ->
            receive
                {proceed, Ref, TimeStartBusyAfterWait, PosBusyAfterWait, TimeInWaiting} ->
                TimeStartBusy = undefined, 
                PosBusy = undefined,
                {ok, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy, TimeInWaiting, PosWaiting, TimeStartBusyAfterWait, PosBusyAfterWait}
            after ?CONF_BACKEND_HTTP_TIMEOUT ->
                ok
            end;
        {proceed, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy} -> 
            PosWaiting = undefined,
            TimeStartBusyAfterWait = undefined, 
            PosBusyAfterWait = undefined, 
            TimeInWaiting = undefined,
            {ok, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy, TimeInWaiting, PosWaiting, TimeStartBusyAfterWait, PosBusyAfterWait};
        unknown_pool -> unknown_pool
end,
case ShouldContinue of
    {ok, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy, TimeInWaiting, PosWaiting, TimeStartBusyAfterWait, PosBusyAfterWait}  ->
         execute_process(BeforeGetConn, Url, Headers, Body, Method, PoolId, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy, TimeStartBusyAfterWait, PosBusyAfterWait, PosWaiting, TimeInWaiting);
    ok ->
        execute_process(BeforeGetConn, Url, Headers, Body, Method, PoolId, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined);
    unknown_pool ->
         ...
end.
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you set `TimeStartBusy` and `PosBusy` to `undefined` at the beginning of the function, so the case clause `{proceed, TimeStartBusy, PosBusy}` can only match the tuple `{proceed, undefined, undefined}`.  The actual value is `{proceed,{1614,588434,663546},1}`, so it does not match.

Unlike most other languages, Erlang variables are single-assignment: once you've set the value of a variable, there is no way to change it, not even in a pattern match like in a case clause. To do what you want, just remove the lines that set the variables to `undefined` before the case expression. That way, the variables get assigned during the match.

Comment: Okay, but if I unassign the variables, now, it throws this error: `'PosBusy' insecure in 'case'.` For each variable that was previously initialized to undefined

Comment: This happens because `PosBusy` is assigned in some but not all case clauses. Therefore, you can't use it after the case expression, since it may or may not have a value at that point.

Comment: Now, i added this to the code, (you can see it in the code snippet) but still showing the same error

Comment: It's a similar issue there: `PosBusy` is matched against in the case clause, which means that it should be assigned either in all code paths leading to that point or none of them. It might be easier to move the second case expression into a separate function - that lets you start with a "clean slate", with the only defined variables being the ones passed as function arguments.